# How does Random Forest Classifier determine the final classification

Tags: python, classification, random-forest

I understand that the Random Forest Classifier uses aggregation over the decision trees to determine the final classification.

I read here: https://www.datascience.com/blog/classification-random-forests-in-python

"Random forest is an ensemble decision tree algorithm because the final prediction, in the case of a regression problem, is an average of the predictions of each individual decision tree; in classification, it's the average of the most frequent prediction"

I am interested in  finding out what my RFC's final decision path is i.e which tree's did it take the average from (this appears to be tree with 'the most frequent predictions')

I am just not sure I understand what it means by the most frequent predictions, say I have 3 classes (1, 2, 3) and the RFC predicts class 3 the most frequently, does this mean the meta RFC would take an average of all trees which predicted class 3? This seems intuitively wrong.

Could someone please explain this for me?

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on [Data Science Stack exchange ](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/); I am not sure if a question on algorithm falls within StackOverflow remit, as no code is involved, but I might be wrong in which case ignore me!

Comment: @nickthefreak oh okay, I didn't know about that site. Thanks.